# using SQL aggregate functions with JOINs

Tags: join, group-by, sybase, aggregate

I have two tables - tool_downloads and tool_configurations. I am trying to retrieve the most recent build date for each tool in my database. The layout of the DB is simple. One table called tool_downloads keeps track of when a tool is downloaded. Another table is called tool_configurations and stores the actual data about the tool. They are linked together by the tool_conf_id.

If I run the following query which omits dates, I get back 200 records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.tool_conf_id, b.tool_conf_id
FROM tool_downloads a
JOIN tool_configurations b 
ON a.tool_conf_id = b.tool_conf_id
ORDER BY a.tool_conf_id
```

When I try to add in date information I get back hundreds of thousands of records! Here is the query that fails horribly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.tool_conf_id, max(a.configured_date) as config_date, b.configuration_name
FROM tool_downloads a
JOIN tool_configurations b
ON a.tool_conf_id = b.tool_conf_id
ORDER BY a.tool_conf_id
```

I know the problem has something to do with group-bys/aggregate data and joins. I can't really search google since I don't know the name of the problem I'm encountering. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is:

```
SELECT b.tool_conf_id, b.configuration_name, max(a.configured_date) as config_date
  FROM tool_downloads a
    JOIN tool_configurations b
      ON a.tool_conf_id = b.tool_conf_id
  GROUP BY b.tool_conf_id, b.configuration_name
```